# jQuery .text() including button's text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using select2 for one of my dropdownlists and I have a jquery event listener for when a selection is made.  Basically, once a selection is made, that selection is then populated into an `ul` element. The text part of the `li` element in the `ul` will have a button for removing that option from the `ul`.  If that option is removed from the `ul` then it is populated back into my select list.

Here is my jQuery for adding selected options to the `ul`:

```
$("#My-DDL").on("select2:select",
    function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.params);
        $("#My-UL-Element").append("<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-info text-dark' data-id='" +
            evt.params.data.id +
            "' ><small>" +
            evt.params.data.text +
            "</small> <button type='button' class='close remove-button'>&times;</button></li>");
        $("#My-DDL option[value='" + evt.params.data.id + "']").remove();
        $("#My-DDL").val("").change();
    });
```

Here is my jQuery for when an option is removed from the `ul` element and populated back into `My-DDL`:

```
function removeCapability() {
    $("#My-UL-Element").on("click",
        ".remove-button",
        function () {
            console.log($(this).parent().text());
            console.log($(this).parent().data("id"));
            var elementId = $(this).parent().data("id");
            $("#My-DDL").append(new Option($(this).parent()
                .text(),
                elementId)); // add item back to dropdownlist

            /* sort the dropdownlist options back to the original way */
            var selectList = $("#My-DDL option");
            selectList.sort(function (a, b) {
                a = a.value;
                b = b.value;
                return a - b;
            });
            $("#My-DDL").html(selectList);
            /* End of Sort */

            $(this).parent().remove(); // remove item from ul element
        });
}
```

Now, my problem deals with the second part of when an item is removed from the `ul` and populated back into the select.  When an item is removed.. the `$(this).parent().text()` includes the `&times;` from the button.. which I can understand because it is the *text* of the that element, but how do I ignore the button text?

**UPDATE**

The question above can be answered by focusing on the text inside the `small` element.  Let me rephrase with a different scenario.. how would I accomplish this if the text didn't have a `small` element?

```
$("#My-DDL").on("select2:select",
    function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.params);
        $("#My-UL-Element").append("<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-info text-dark' data-id='" +
            evt.params.data.id +
            "' >" +
            evt.params.data.text +
            " <button type='button' class='close remove-button'>&times;</button></li>");
        $("#My-DDL option[value='" + evt.params.data.id + "']").remove();
        $("#My-DDL").val("").change();
    });
```

Comment: You can do `$(this).parent().find('small').text()`

Comment: If you are only interested in the text content of the `small` element - well then select that, instead of the whole parent …?

Comment: @Satpal @CBroe Honestly I didn't even think of that because I am just now starting to get into Bootstrap 4.. and I just added the `small` part.  Sorry for the dumb/early-morning question

Comment: @Satpal sorry, I have other dropdownlists that do the same thing but the text portion doesn't contain `small`.  How would I do that then? Updated my question

Comment: @CBroe Updated my question

Comment: Since you are removing the LI from the list in that case anyway, you could remove the button from the LI first, and then get the LI text content ... Or you store the info you need in a custom data attribute or using https://api.jquery.com/data/, so that you can retrieve it again from there, so that the “polution” of the text value by additional buttons etc doesn’t matter any more.

Comment: @CBroe great idea!  I used a data attribute.  Thank you for your help.  If you want to post an answer I will accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are removing the LI from the list in that case anyway, you could remove the button from the LI first, and then get the LI text content ...

But preferably, you would rather store the info you need in a custom data attribute or using https://api.jquery.com/data/, so that you can retrieve it again from there - so that the “pollution” of the text value by additional buttons etc. doesn’t matter any more.

That way you separate the actual data more from the presentation. Whatever else you might apply/add to that text shown in the LI at a later point won’t affect your script in that regard any more.

Answer (score 1):

A quick vanilla JS function to get the text nodes within a parent, and concatenate them into one string:

```js
function getText(el) {
  return Array.from(el.childNodes).filter(e =>
    e.nodeType == 3 // text node
  ).map(e =>
    e.nodeValue
  ).join(" ");
}

console.log(getText(document.getElementById("demo")));
```

```html
<div id='demo'>
  Part 1
  <button>Button!</button>
  Part 2
</div>
```